# Telnet and SSH calling in main file, Telnet works but ssh fails

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, telnetlib

I am new to python, I am writing a script to 'telenet' device IP in some cases and SSH username@deviceIp if telnet faiils..

For all Telnet IP's it work perfectly.. But when i am doing "ssh admin@153.88.127.21" the below code fails and I get error in try bloc itself like "socket.error" for ssh device's.

I want ssh devices to enter else block,, if telnet Ip fails in try block.

In my Main.py file

```
    try:
        #TELNET MODULE CALL
        tn= _telnetMOD._telnet(username, password, device)
        break
    else:
        #SSH MODULE CALL
        ssh= _sshMOD._ssh(username, password, device)
```

In _telnetMod file i have below code which works
    import telnetlib

```
def _telnet(_userVar,_passwordVAR, _device):
    tn=''
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(_device,23)
    #PYTHON VERSION 2.6 AND HIGHER
    tn.read_until("Username: ",10)
    tn.write(_userVar + "\r")
    if _passwordVAR:
        tn.read_until("Password: ",10)
        tn.write(_passwordVAR + "\r")    
    return tn
```

In _sshMOD file i have below code which fails and not sure of below code

```
import paramiko 

def _ssh(_userVar,_passwordVAR, _device):
    ssh=''
    ssh= paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.connect(_device, username=_userVar,password=_passwordVAR)
    return ssh
```

Comment: What happens when you try to ssh to that system on the command line with the same username and password?  Does it work?

Comment: Are you certain that the sshd daemon is running on the target host?

Comment: yes I tried in the command line it works perfectly.. this is command i ran "ssh admin@153.88.127.21"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forgot the client.load_system_host_keys()? This is an example from the docs:

```
client = SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect('ssh.example.com')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls -l')
```

And you should use the try block like this:

```
try:
    telnet()
except:
    telnet = false
if telnet == false:
    try:
        ssh()
    ...
```